# Help Installing SAP GUI 740

Tags: software-installation, java

I get this error, should I try a new download or is something I should get from somewhere else?
Thanks

```
java -jar PlatinGUI740_0-20012039.JAR
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sap/platin/micro/Microkernel : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the same behavior as you do with OpenJDK-7.

I solved it by installing version 8 of OpenJDK. If you are using Ubuntu 14.10, then you can installing with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

and then selecting it using `update-alternatives --config java`

In my case, the output of `update-alternatives --config java` now looks like the following:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1069      manual mode
```

Installation followed properly after that.

Hope this helps!